# How to install all .exe in a folder using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to develop the following algorithm:

For all files in the current folder (folder containing the script) do:
install the files one by one

```
cls
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 set arch=x86
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 set arch=x64

for /r "%~dp0" %%m in ("*.exe") do (
    set expath=%%m
    set exfile=%%~nm

    expath :: execute the .exe files
)
echo.
echo Done! 
echo.
pause
goto :eof

echo %exfile%
```

Comment: you don't want to start `expath`, but `%expath%`.

Comment: @Stephan, you are right. And `::` is not a comment indicator

Comment: It sort of is. It's technically a label, but it acts like a comment because of how batch treats labels. It's worth noting that if you want inline comments in batch, you need a `&REM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little batch file starts each .exe file in directory of the batch file as separate process. Batch processing is halted after starting an executable until the started application terminated itself.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("%~dp0*.exe") do (
    start "Running %%~nI" /wait "%%I"
)
endlocal
```

For the details on the used commands, open a command prompt window and run there the following command lines to get displayed the help for each command:

- `for /?`
- `start /?`