# Software installation automatically when first booting complete

Tags: windows, installation, formatting, boot

I have created bootable pendrive that for installing Windows.

Now I want to know that, is there any way to install some basic software after completion of booting.I just want to install all software automatically that is already kept in bootable drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all exe in some folder using batch file see here: [How to install all .exe in a folder using a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627078/how-to-install-all-exe-in-a-folder-using-a-batch-file)

if you want that to happen automatically without user interaction then you need to customize the windows OS installer (installation Image).